# How to iterate through multidimentional array and show Index

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

I am writing a program where i am using Multi-dimensional array. The concept will enter the subject name and index will be shown that who student is studying that subject.

```
$var= [ 'Abdullah'=>['full_name'=>'Abdullah_Faraz',
                 'Subject'=>['English','Urdu','Maths']],

    'Hamid'=>['full_name'=>'Hamid_Amjad', 
                 'Subject'=>['PHP','Urdu','C++']],

    'Abid'=>['full_name'=>'Abid_Ali',
                 'Subject'=>['OOP','OS','Calculus']],

    'Aqeel'=>['full_name'=>'Aqeel_Bhutta',
                 'Subject'=>['Economics','Statistics','Big_Data']]
```

];

```
foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
 foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
    foreach ($value1 as $value2) {

        if($value2='Urdu'){
            echo $key;
    }       
}
}
```

Output
     Abdullah
     Hamid

but now i want to show the index of those who are not studying Urdu the expected outcome should be

```
 Abid
 Aqeel
```

But i don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this

```
foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
    $lang = $value['Subject'][1];
    if($lang != 'Urdu'){
        echo $key.'<br>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your inner two *foreach* loops with normal for-loop over array length.

```
<?php 
for ($x = 0; $x < dim-Length; $x++) {
    echo "The number is: $x <br>";
} 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 foreach ($var as $key => $value) {
     $flag = 0;
     foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
        foreach ($value1 as $value2) {

          if($value2=='Urdu'){
              $flag =1;
              echo $value;
         }       
     }
     if($flag == 0){
         echo $key
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below codes:

```
//study 'Urdu'               
foreach($var as $nickname => $data){
    if (in_array('Urdu', $data['Subject']))
        echo $nickname . "<br>";
}

//not study 'Urdu'
foreach($var as $nickname => $data){
    if (!in_array('Urdu', $data['Subject']))
        echo $nickname . "<br>";

}
```

Comment: super exact logic. now i have to see what if i enter multiple subjects.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of task can be done simpler with [functional programming](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Functional-Programming.html). Basically, you need to filter array of students by some predicate (for example, subjects they study or do not study). We can write [higher-order function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function) for this. It will use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
function filterStudensBySubject($students, callable $subjectCriteria = null)
{
    if (is_null($subjectCriteria)) {
        $subjectCriteria = function ($subject) {
            return true;
        };
    }

    return array_filter($students, function ($student) use ($subjectCriteria) {
        if (!isset($student['Subject'])) {
            return false;
        }

        return $subjectCriteria($student);
    });
}
```

Then we can write some criterias to supply to this function:

```
$subjects = ['Urdu'];
$studySubjects = function ($student) use ($subjects) {
    return !empty(array_intersect($student['Subject'], $subjects));
};
$doesNotStudySubjects = function ($student) use ($subjects) {
    return empty(array_intersect($student['Subject'], $subjects));
};
```

We have used [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to get an array of elements that present in both arrays.

Finally, we can get students who study subjects and who don't:

```
$studentsWhoStudySubjects = filterStudensBySubject($var, $studySubjects);
$studentsWhoDoNotStudySubjects = filterStudensBySubject($var, $doesNotStudySubjects);
```

Here is [working demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ece1e1409dd832ee1b2ace660e2407afca380ece).

**This approach will allow you to use the same function with any criteria concerning subject (study only two subject, study no more than three subjects, etc.) without rewriting looping logic.**

Addition:

You were asking about displaying keys:

```
$echoKey = function ($key) {
    echo $key, PHP_EOL;
};

$keys = array_keys($studentsWhoStudySubjects);
array_walk($keys, $echoKey);

echo PHP_EOL;

$keys = array_keys($studentsWhoDoNotStudySubjects);
array_walk($keys, $echoKey);
```

Read about [`array_keys`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) and [`array_walk`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

**This may look like a lot of code for such trivial task. But this approach helps you to learn to write decoupled reusable code. As I mentioned we can use our `filterStudensBySubject` function to filter students by any condition (that regards subject) without the need to rewrite the function itself.**

Answer (score 0):

My bit contribution if we want to check multiple Subjects

```
 $arr= array('English','Urdu','Big_Data');

  //study 'Urdu'
    foreach ($var as $key => $data) {
        if (array_intersect($arr, $data['Subject'])) {
            echo $key . "<br>";
        }
    }
```

This will compare $arr with all the Subjects and return the Index.